# How to infer correct type in <select> element?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have a Material select UI element:

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={sortType}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <MenuItem value={'release_date'}>Release date</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'title'}>Title</MenuItem>
  {/* <MenuItem value={'Date added'}>Date added</MenuItem> */}
</Select>
```

As you can see the value is a string `release_date` or `title`. I want to sort a array based on what option has been selected:

```
type IMovie = {
  title: string;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  id: number;
  type?: any;
};

const handleChange = event => {
  setSortType(event.target.value);
  const type = event.target.value;

  localforage.getItem<IMovie []>('trackedMovies').then((value) => {
    let trackedMovies = value;
    trackedMovies = orderBy(trackedMovies, [movie => movie.type], ['asc']);
  })    
};
```

This doesn't work, I think it's because the `trackedMovies = orderBy(trackedMovies, [movie => movie.type], ['asc']);` is of type `any`.

If I replace the type with a `IMovie` property like `title` or `release_date` the `sortBy` does work:

```
 trackedMovies = orderBy(trackedMovies, [movie => movie.type], ['asc']);
```

If I change the value in the `MenuItem`: `<MenuItem value={release_date}>Release date</MenuItem>` I get a error that:

> Cannot find name 'release_date'.

Which makes sense because there's no reference to `{release_date}`. I could solve this by using a switch but it would be much easier/better (I think) to use the direct value of the `MenuItem` to decide what the `sortBy` method should do.

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching my functionality wrong (I think). `sortBy` uses the value of the assigned property to sort. I thought it was using the type property (which was very wrong).

So I created a function `retunSortType` that takes the movie object as a argument. In the function it uses a switch to find what sort type is being used and then returns the correct type (title or release date).

```
const returnSortType = (movie) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'release_date':
      return movie.release_date;      
    case 'title':
      return movie.title;
  }
}

localforage.getItem<IMovie []>('trackedMovies').then((value) => {
  let trackedMovies = value;
  trackedMovies = orderBy(trackedMovies, [movie => returnSortType(movie)], ['asc']);
})
```

It works, it's kind of readable and more options can be added through the switch so I'm kinda happy about it. Still feel there's a better solution though.